# Ruby: can GC::Profiler.enable in production environment cause performance issue?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, memory, profiling

Can activating the GC::Profiler in ruby 1.9.2 in a production environment can cause performance issue? Is it safe to use it in a performance critical production application?

Answer (score 5):

Simply activating `GC::Profiler` shouldn't cause a performance drop, the question is however what you plan to do with it.

Compare it with `Rails.config.log_level`. If you set this too high (like `:notice`), it needs to write a lot of data to the log file, causing a much higher IO than needed and thus causing performance drops. That is why the logger is set to `:debug` in production, to minimize IO operations.

So if you enable `GC::Profiler` and only poll specific results in edge-case scenarios then I don't believe there should be a problem, it is when you start to overuse the profiler that things can start to slow down.

*but this goes for everything, from overusing database queries, to overusing complex code to overusing images, etc...*

Comment: Actually I am using it to get reporting in newrelic, so I guess the data is recorded for every request ?

Comment: In that case, I would advice you to contact them directly. Perhaps they can tell you how (often) they poll. I am sure they can tell you how to avoid any significant impact on your service.

Comment: @Alex have you contacted NewRelic? What did they answered to you?